# KDB/Q add two table by rows

Tags: kdb

I have two table with the same column
I want to create one table with the rows of each two table like

```
     ask  ask_qty exchange_name_ask       bid  bid_qty exchange_name_bid
0  19166.73   0.0260           b'Gate'  19164.61   0.1042           b'Gate'
1  19167.21   0.0521           b'Gate'  19164.16   0.0103           b'Gate'
2  19167.63   0.1200           b'Gate'  19163.92   0.0296           b'Gate'
3  19168.27   0.1304           b'Gate'  19162.39   0.1304           b'Gate'
```

AND

```
     ask  ask_qty exchange_name_ask       bid  bid_qty exchange_name_bid
0  19169.13   0.1200           b'CoinBase'  19159.90   0.1200           b'CoinBase'
1  19171.36   0.2608           b'CoinBase'  19158.95   0.0291           b'CoinBase'
2  19172.18   0.5215           b'CoinBase'  19158.69   0.0106           b'CoinBase'
3  19173.59   0.0102           b'CoinBase'  19157.86   0.2609           b'CoinBase'
```

GET

```
        ask  ask_qty exchange_name_ask       bid  bid_qty exchange_name_bid
0  19166.73   0.0260           b'Gate'  19164.61   0.1042           b'Gate'
1  19167.21   0.0521           b'Gate'  19164.16   0.0103           b'Gate'
2  19167.63   0.1200           b'Gate'  19163.92   0.0296           b'Gate'
3  19168.27   0.1304           b'Gate'  19162.39   0.1304           b'Gate'
4  19169.13   0.1200           b'CoinBase'  19159.90   0.1200           b'CoinBase'
5  19171.36   0.2608           b'CoinBase'  19158.95   0.0291           b'CoinBase'
6  19172.18   0.5215           b'CoinBase'  19158.69   0.0106           b'CoinBase'
7  19173.59   0.0102           b'CoinBase'  19157.86   0.2609           b'CoinBase'
```

Thanks

Comment: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/joins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the tables have matching schema, just `join (,)` should suffice:

`gateTbl,coinbaseTbl`

Answer (score 2):

assume tables a and b

```
a uj b
or
a,b
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of union join here as your tables are not keyed, the tables are simply appended to each other.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/uj/ has more useful information on uj.

As suggested by others, you can do table1,table2 or ,[table1;table2] as your columns and schema are the same.